# How Can I use a typename, which is defined in Derived Class, in the Base Class with CRTP pattern?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++20, c++-concepts, crtp

I am trying to implement a input stream wrapper, which is designed to handle streams with `char` or `wchar_t` with same interfaces.

There is the code of the base class:

```cpp
template <typename _StreamWrapperT>
concept HasChType = requires { typename _StreamWrapperT::Ch; };

template <HasChType _StreamT>
class BasicInputStreamWrapper
{
using Ch = typename _StreamT::Ch; // the Ch type is defined in derived class

    BasicInputStreamWrapper(Ch* buffer, size_t bufferSize)
        : buffer_(buffer)
        , bufferSize_(bufferSize)
        , current_(buffer_)
        , count_(0)
        , readCount_(0)
        , eof_(false)
    {
        read();
    }



    virtual void read() = 0;

    const Ch* peek4() { return (current_ + 4 - !eof_ <= bufferLast_) ? current_ : nullptr; }
    Ch        peek() { return *current_; }
    size_t    tell() { return count_ + static_cast<size_t>(current_ - buffer_); }
    Ch        take()
    {
        Ch c = *current_;
        read();
        return c;
    }

protected:
    size_t bufferSize_;
    size_t count_;
    size_t readCount_;
    Ch*    buffer_;
    Ch*    bufferLast_;
    Ch*    current_;
    bool   eof_;
};
```

Then I tried to derive a `FileReadStream` from it:

```cpp
class FileReadStream : public BasicInputStreamWrapper<FileReadStream> // ERR: NOT satisfy the concept `HasChType`
{
public:
    using Ch = char;

    FileReadStream()  = delete;
    ~FileReadStream() = default;

    FileReadStream(std::FILE* fp, Ch* buffer, size_t bufferSize);
    void read() override;

    // not implemented
    void put(Ch) { IPDF_ASSERT(false); }
    void put(Ch, size_t) { IPDF_ASSERT(false); }
    void flush() { IPDF_ASSERT(false); }

private:
    std::FILE* fp_;
}
```

Then I got the error hint:
[image]

How to resolve it?

Comment: In future questions please post errors as text, not screenshots

Comment: Define a traits struct to extract the `Ch` type of the derived class, something like https://godbolt.org/z/q1z1vK5Mf